# Can't use onClickImageListener on a Fragment swipetabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

I've been trying to add images to a fragment of swipe tab which will be clicked to open another activity but it is not yet working!

I have a swipe tab activity which has three fragments first as intro second to be made a menu and third just information but i can't make that menu i want that menu to be manually made image and that will be clicked for the next relating activity inside it. Help me

Fragment Code:-

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {
ImageView img;
public TwoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    img = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TwoFragment.this, Programming.class);
            startActivity(intent);
     }
  });


  }
}
```

Adding Images: [Image of fragment in which the image will be clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6eSB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `TwoFragment.this` as the first parameter of Intent, pass `getActivity()` like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Programming.class);
        startActivity(intent);
 }
```

**Explanation**: The first parameter should be of type `Context`, this is why passing an activity works, reason being that the Activity extends Context (indirectly). Fragment does not, hence passing a fragment there will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.layoutid, Programming.class);
            transaction.commit();
```

}

```
    Here 'R.id.layoutid' is your main layout id of R.layout.fragment_two layout file.
```